# Using ValidateSet() with object type

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I have a parameter that is used in three different parameter sets, and based on which set it is in, the type will be different. While the snip below is syntactically correct, when I attempt to leverage it I'm receiving an error. I do something similar in another function where my validateset is a collection of classes I have defined which may be misleading as those are defined within the powershell module and not "proper" .Net types.

```
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'string')]
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'integer')]
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'number')]
    [ValidateSet([string],[int],[decimal])]
    $default,
```

Resulting error

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'default'. The argument "black" does not belong to the set "string,int,decimal" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ValidateScript` attribute instead:

```
[ValidateScript({$_ -is [string] -or $_ -is [int] -or $_ -is [decimal]})]
[object]$default,
```

Comment: Good call, I was kind of thinking along those lines as well, would the param then need to be defined as [object] or could it just be whatever

Comment: You can remove the `[object]` type constraint (un-typed parameters default to `[object]` anyway), but you can't define it as "whatever" :) the trick here is that `[string]`, `[int]` and `[decimal]` all derive from `[object]`, either directly or indirectly